# I can get A3/P3 instead of AM/PM in datetime picker error vb.net

Tags: vb.net

```
 Private Sub CboPurpose_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cboPurpose.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim formatdate As Date
    If cboPurpose.Text = "Select" Then
        MsgBox("Please Choose your Purpose.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)

    ElseIf cboPurpose.Text = "Photocopy" Then
        formatdate = DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 1, Now)
        txtdue.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
        txtdue.CustomFormat = Format(formatdate, ("dd-MM-yyyy  hh:mm tt"))
    ElseIf cboPurpose.Text = "Overnight" Then
        formatdate = DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 2, Now)
        txtdue.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
        txtdue.CustomFormat = Format(formatdate, ("dd-MM-yyyy   hh:mm tt"))
    ElseIf cboPurpose.Text = "Borrow Until Weekends" Then
        formatdate = DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 3, Now)
        txtdue.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
        txtdue.CustomFormat = Format(formatdate, ("dd-MM-yyyy   hh:mm tt "))
    End If
End Sub
```

I'm Having trouble when i select a text in my combo box .. I get the the output like this
 `"01/01/2020  12:12: A3"` instead of `"01/01/2020  12:12: AM or PM"`
 i tried some several changes in my code but i can'g get it right.

Comment: Never use that `Format` method. If you have a value that you want to format, call its `ToString` method and provide the format specifier, e.g. `myTextBox.Text = myDate.ToString("d/MM/yyyy")` or `myLabel.Text = myDecimal.ToString("c2")`. If you want to perform composite formatting then use the `String.Format` method or string interpolation.

Comment: that txtdue is datetimepicker sir

Comment: Never use that `DateAdd` method. If you want to add a time interval to a `Date` then use the methods it provides, e.g. `formatDate = Date.Now.AddDays(2)`.

Comment: *"that txtdue is datetimepicker"*. Who cares? Do you not know what an example is? Don't use `Format` to format dates and numbers. That's it, that's all. It doesn't matter what else you're doing or what controls you're using. Apart from that, you don't need to format anything when using a `DateTimePicker`, as I've explained in my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Lines like this are nonsensical:

```
txtdue.CustomFormat = Format(formatdate, ("dd-MM-yyyy   hh:mm tt "))
```

You are using a format specifier to format a date and then assigning that to the `CustomFormat` property. The idea is that you you assign the format specifier to the `CustomFormat` property and then the control uses that to format whatever date it contains.  That should be:

```
txtdue.CustomFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm tt"
```

Comment: i tried your code sir. it doesn't add the date with dateinterval in my txtdue. but it changes to AM and PM thanks to this

Comment: @glendonnolo _it doesn't add the date with dateinterval in my txtdue_ Because you forgot to assign the new date to the `txtdue.Value` property. Check the comments above, the part: `formatDate = Date.Now.AddDays(2)`, after that you need to add `txtdue.Value = formatDate`.